# How to create a primary key in a CREATE TABLE...SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table from an existing table using this:

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE survey_results_activities_temp
              SELECT e.id, taxyear, employee_email, w2_wages, employee_title, department, job_code, cc.cost_center_name, e.consultant, pr.cost_center as cost_center_pharma, pr.risk as risk_pharma
              FROM employees e, cost_center cc, pharma_risk pr
              WHERE e.email='$_SESSION[userid]' AND e.campaign= '$_SESSION[campaign]' AND e.qualified=1 AND cc.id=e.department AND cc.pharma_like=pr.id";
```

I'd like to make e.id into a Primary key. I tried using SELECT PRIMARY KEY(e.id) but this fails.  How can I make e.id into a primary key? The employees.id is already a primary key.

Comment: I do not know what the sense of your query because this table is completely useless , but you can try use a concat

    Select Concat(e.Id, ‚ Primary key‘)....

Comment: While I think you can do this in one query, I always just execute an ALTER TABLE afterwards

Comment: The [`create table...select` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) have an example. Also, do not use string concatenation to add values to a SQL query, it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use [bind parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add table definition to the query.

```php
$sql = "CREATE TABLE survey_results_activities_temp (
                   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                   taxyear INT NOT NULL,
                   employee_email VARCHAR(255),
                   ... , 
                   risk_pharma INT )
        SELECT e.id, taxyear, employee_email, w2_wages, employee_title, department, job_code, cc.cost_center_name, e.consultant, pr.cost_center as cost_center_pharma, pr.risk as risk_pharma
        FROM employees e, cost_center cc, pharma_risk pr
        WHERE e.email='$_SESSION[userid]' AND e.campaign= '$_SESSION[campaign]' AND e.qualified=1 AND cc.id=e.department AND cc.pharma_like=pr.id";
```

Of course, datatypes and other definition details are fake, adjust them.

Remember - the names of columns in output list of SELECT query must match the column names in table definition strictly!

Final columns order in the table will match their order in output list in SELECT part, not columns definition order in CREATE part.

Answer (score 1):

This a simple example of creating a table with primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```